# AngularJS : Directive Isolated Scope Undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am writing a directive with an `isolate scope` with a two-way binding in `AngularJS`. However, I cannot seem to get the two-way binding to work. No matter what I do, the `populate` property on the `isolate scope` is always `undefined` (although the property does exist) instead of being the value it's supposed to be bound to.

HTML:

```
<html>
  <body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
      {{data.dataProp}} <!-- demonstrates that data.dataProp is defined -->
      <scope-fail data-source="data.dataProp"></scope-fail>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
angular.module("MyApp", [])
.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    dataProp: 'Some Data'
  }
})
.directive('scopeFail', function ($window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      populate: '=dataSource'
    },
    template: '<div>Value: {{populate}}</div>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log('Scope property:', scope.populate); //prints Scope property: undefined
    }
  };
})
```

CodePen with above code: [CodePen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVKMaJ)

So why doesn't the CodePen show "Value: Some Data"? What I think is supposed to happen is that `populate` binds to the value of `data-source` on the custom element which is `data.dataProp` on the controller scope which is `Some Data`.

Where am I going wrong with this/how can I get the isolate scope to have a two-way binding with the data-source attribute?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Either change `populate: '=dataSource'` to `populate: '=source'` or add an extra `data-` attribute prefix to `data-source`. AngularJS automatically strips the `data-` attribute to allow for valid html5 scoped attributes.

Comment: this solved the problem for me! This makes sense and thanks for catching that my attribute started with `data-`. ! I'll mark this answer as correct sometime tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong syntax. It should be this

```
.directive('scopeFail', function ($window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      dataSource: '='
    },
    template: '<div>Value: {{scope.dataSource}}</div>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log('Scope property:', scope.dataSource); //prints Scope property: undefined
    }
  };
})
```

The scope properties are passed in as attributes by the attribute name, and you define the data binding as two way, evaluate, or read only.

**EDIT**

csbarnes answer will also work since `dataSource: '='` is just shorthand for `dataSource: '=dataSource'` but it makes readability and debugging more difficult IMO. I find it easier to keep the attribute names and scope properties the same. But to each their own.

Comment: `dataSource: '='` is just shorthand for `dataSource: '=dataSource'`. Checkout the [AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive) examples on isolated scopes.

Comment: I still have the same problem if I paste this directive code over my old directive code into a new [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwXjVG). csbarnes' answer makes sense and solves the problem for me - thanks for the note about style though, I'll try to keep the names of my scope properties and attributes the same in the future