# pass data from directive to controller

Tags: angularjs

how is it possible to bind a variable inside a controller to a ng-model of an input tag inside a directive  in angular?

here is the code im working on which is not working:
inside directive html:

```
<input kendo-auto-complete k-data-source="data" ng-model="myValue"  style="width: 100%;" />
```

my directive script:

```
 app.directive('myAutocomplete', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            data: '=info',
           }
        templateUrl: '/directive.html',
        transclude: true,
        link: link,
        controller:function() {
            var a = 4;
        }
    };
```

calling the directive somewhere else:

```
    <my-autocomplete info="vm.people"  ng-hide="dialogIsHidden"></my-autocomplete>{{myValue}}
```

Comment: What is k-data-source?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31393812/angularjs-directive-isolated-scope-undefined

Comment: k-data is for kendo telerik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have errors in the code you've showed, for example you are missing a comma after the `scope` property and you seem to be referencing a function `link` which you either haven't written or you're hiding it from us.

It looks like you are trying to use an isolate scope to share data between the controller and directive where you have data two-way bound between the directive and controller. I think this is probably the way to go but you haven't quite implemented it correctly due to some of the errors above.

Here's a simplified demo of what (I think) you are trying to achieve.

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/5NjO3vJnMVdNCGJOFeyN)

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  var vm = this;

  vm.someData = {
    value: 'bar'
  };

});


app.directive('myAutocomplete', [function(){

    return {

        restrict: 'E',

        scope: {
            someData: '=',
        },

        templateUrl: 'directive.html',


    };

}]);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.17/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.17"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
    <pre>{{vm.someData}}</pre>
     <my-autocomplete some-data='vm.someData'></my-autocomplete>
  </body>

</html>
```

**directive.html**

```
<input 
  type="text"
  ng-model="someData.value"  
/>
```

Comment: thanx alot what you explained worked correctly and sorry for an incomplete explanation of me

Comment: Glad to help. If you found it helpful could you please mark it as the accepted answer or upvote the answer. Would appreciate it.